# Efficiency of 24/7 AJAX polling

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, performance

I have a request to provide the following solution:

Two web pages with 1 form on them. This form is submitted and inserted into a database. Another web page is used to display the results of the form inputs in a tag cloud solution. My question is what exact workflow would people use for this? My thoughts were like so:

1 MySQL database, 1 html page running AJAX and jQuery for the tag cloud/polling. 1 PHP processing script which grabs new data from the database and serves it out to the html page. Now, what is the effect of this being ran for say 24 hours, constantly updating via AJAX ie, every 10 seconds or should i use a different method. The results from the form need to be saved for offline viewing after the 24 hour period, so i cant just stream the form results straight to the page.

All advice welcome using any technologies...

Should add, there's a possibility that it may be on a LAN with no internet access, possibly thinking of a local XAMPP installation...

Comment: How many clients will be doing the polling at the same time?

Comment: @Inerdia up to 3, but no more!

Comment: HTTP push such as http://www.stream-hub.com/ or http://www.ape-project.org/, this way the server tells client when there is data and there is no constant polling required. Edit: with max clients being only 3 it's probably not needed.

Comment: 3 simultaneous clients polling once every ten seconds is less than one request per second. Just pick whichever approach is easiest to code.

Answer (score 2):

given that there is 3 clients, and they poll every 10 sec, that means
approx 25k requests per day to keep the page updated. which is hardly any load for a xampp install, especially on a local network.

i would suggest testing the polling and see if it still works after 24hours.
are there any limitations in the browser that stop the script from working after x amount of time. (i have never tried that long before sorry)

an alternative approach is, 
does it need to poll continuously, or can you just have a refresh button